# Multi-key dictionary/list

Tags: c#

We have a multi-tenant application with running site instances stored in a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, SiteInstance>`, where `string` is the hostname of the site.

We now have the requirement to support multiple hostnames per site instance. As a temporary solution I'm searching first by key and if no match is found, then performing a LINQ query against the dictionary to find an instance with a matching hostname.

Is there a better/faster performing solution here?

Note: The list of hostnames mapped to each site instance is variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not use multiple key-value pairs with the same `SiteInstance` and different keys?

```
var instance = new SiteInstance();
dict.TryAdd("hostname1", instance); // in actual code, you should check
dict.TryAdd("hostname2", instance); // TryAdd's return value
```

The hostnames must be unique. To *access distinct* `SiteInstance` objects (edit due to comments), you could either use an additional `HashSet<SiteInstance>` or use LINQ (not threadsafe, however):

```
var instances = dict.Values.Distinct();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option as each site instance maintains state that needs to shared regardless of the hostname. Plus as I mentioned, the number of hostnames per site is variable.

Comment: OK, but I don't see a problem with these requirements: 1) If you use the *same* `SiteInstance` object (not just equal), they share the same state. Values in a dictionary do not have to be unique, 2) You can connect any number of keys (hostnames) to a single value... what point am I missing?

Comment: All good points, I just think Paul's solution is tidier. There will be numerous cases where we need to access distinct running instances. This is much easier if we have only one dictionary entry per instance.

Comment: I would add that whilst Paul's solution is tidier, it is also substantially more complex due to how we have to calculate the Hash Code. Unless I can figure how to do this I'll go for your solution.

Comment: Maybe an `int` field for the hashcode, and each time you add or remove a hostname from the inner set you could `xor` it (or any other `f(x)` with `f(x) equals f^-1(x)`). This would enable you to `GetHashCode` in const time by returning the field value. (But take it with a grain of salt. There are people with much better understanding on how to compute hashcodes with few collisions.)

Comment: I think the difficulty is that the key we use as a lookup will only ever contain one hostname whereas the stored keys will likely contain more. I can't see how we could create a hashcode function where `[ "www.foo.com", "www.bar.com"].GetHashCode() == ["www.bar.com"].GetHashCode()`

Comment: OK, I see. Does accessing distinct instances have to be thread-safe too? For distinct instances I could suggest you `dict.Values.Distinct()` or a separate `HashSet<SiteInstance>` along with your `ConcurrentDictionary`, but neither of them is thread-safe unless you take care yourself.

Comment: Thread safety for distinct instances is not so important. According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287109.aspx) we should be able to use ToArray() to get a point in time snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

Having just written a complex answer, I've seen @Mudu's answer, and it is obviously a much better method if it is that simple.  Anyhow, here's mine... guess an advantage could be that this would be easily extendable.

Create a small class that inherits from `List<String>`, called  `HostNames`. You could then override the `Equals()` method and `GetHashCode()` to return a match if any of the contents of the list match any other.

You could then use this Class as your dictionary key `ConcurrentDictionary<HostNames, SiteInstance>`

To retrieve values you'd need to build a hostName object:

```
var hostName = new HostNames();
hostName.Add("hostName1");
var siteInstance = concurrentDictionary[hostName];
```

Comment: I like the approach too, although a bit more complex. I would, however, favour an inner `ISet<string>` (`HashSet` for example) (composition over inheritance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and maybe implement `IEnumerable<string>` if needed. The *order* of the strings is presumably irrelevant, so you could do a comparision like `bool equal = true; foreach(var s in thisSet) equal = equal && otherSet.Contains(s);` in less than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Agreed, a private HashSet would be a tidier solution.

Comment: Any pointers on how I should implement `GetHashCode` since this is what the dictionary is using when trying to get a value by key.

Comment: Yes, that could be tricky... do you have to use a Dictionary?  How about a simple class with a '.GetSiteInstance(string hostName)' method?  You could then customise it however you like.